# How can I sanitize my include statements?

Tags: php, security, include

How do I clean this so users can't pull pages outside of the local domain?

```
<?php
 if(!empty($_GET['page']))
 {
  include($_GET['page']);
 }
 else
 {
  include('home.php');
 }
?>
```

Comment: <?php
     if(!empty($_GET['page']))
     {
      include($_GET['page']);
     }
     else
     {
      include('home.php');
     }
    ?>

Comment: Including files where the path is based on user input is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: while I agree w/ Moore, Greg showed a way to do this safely and effectively

Answer (score 12):

The safest way is to whitelist your pages:

```
$page = 'home.php';

$allowedPages = array('one.php', 'two.php', ...);

if (!empty($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], $allowedPages))
    $page = $_GET['page'];

include $page;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// get the absolute file name of the page we want to see
$page = realpath($_GET['page']);

// get the directory in which pages are
$mydir = dirname(__FILE__);

// see if the included page is inside this allowed dir
if ($page === false || substr($page, 0, strlen($mydir) != $mydir) {
 die('go away hacker');
} else {
 include $page;
}
```

Comment: Assuming there was no sensitive information in the "$mydir", this is how I'd probably do it too.

Comment: The best option is to parse the URI (<code>/some/page.html</code>) and use that to determine which file needs to be included (or function called, or class created, or whatever). However, that's not really an answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested. I just wrote it up real quick, but it should work (I hope) and it'll definitely provide you a base for where to get started.

```
define('DEFAULT_PAGE', 'home.php');
define('ALLOWED_PAGES_EXPRESSION', '^[\/]+\.php$|^[\/]+\.html$');

function ValidateRequestedPage($p)
{
    $errors_found = False;

        // Make sure this isn't someone trying to reference directories absolutely.
    if (preg_match('^\/.+$', $p))
    {
        $errors_found = True;
    }

        // Disable access to hidden files (IE, .htaccess), and parent directory.
    if (preg_match('^\..+$', $p))
    {
        $errors_found = True;
    }


        // This shouldn't be needed for secure servers, but test for remote includes just in case...
    if (preg_match('.+\:\/\/.+', $p))
    {
        $errors_found = True;
    }

    if (!preg_match(ALLOWED_PAGES_EXPRESSION, $p))
    {
        $errors_found = True;
    }

    return !$errors_found;
}

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) { $page = DEFAULT_PAGE; }
else { $page = $_GET['page']; }

if ( !ValidateRequestedPage($page) )
{
    /* This is called when an error has occured on the page check. You probably
       want to show a 404 here instead of returning False. */
    return False;
}

// This suggests that a valid page is being used.
require_once($page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a switch statement.

Check if the $_GET var is set and then run it through the cases and have the default go to home.php