# url Query and Security

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

In url query with id I use `is_numeric($_GET['id'])` for security issues. But in query with for example category name, is `urlencode()` a right way for security?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no arguments jasmine...........

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() is not usefull for a file system. Isnt it?
Its not arguments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `urlencode` is used to make strings take URL encoded form.

Unlike with a numeric ID, there is no one single method of sanitizing a string input value. What method you need to use depends on what you want to do with the category name.

For example:

- If you want to use it in a query, run at least a `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it or (better) use a database class that supports parametrized queries (like PDO). With parametrized queries, PDO will take care of securely sanitizing any incoming parameters.
- If you want to output it on a page, you need to run `htmlentities()` on it before outputting to prevent injection of HTML code.

there are other things to take care of when using the category name as a file name, when using it as part of an URL and so on and so on.

Comment: index.php?page=blahblah
what about index.php?page=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749108/urlquey-and-security   ?
I want to print only database items to screen.

Comment: @jasmine if you want to include the file specified in `page`, you need to be extra careful. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799384/how-can-i-sanitize-my-include-statements

Comment: @pekka;
I know this but I dont want to include a page. 
This is a simple query:
$page = urlencode($_GET['page']);
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = %s', mysql_real_escape_string($page));

$page is not numeric.

Comment: @jasmine I see. Don't use `urlencode` for incoming data; otherwise this query should be okay and safe.

Comment: I ask this question pekka, how can it safe with url query? 
Thanks for help

Comment: @jasmine what do you mean by URL query?

Comment: @pekka ;Thanks for htmlentities() 
;)