# Apache Url are not being reading correctly, rewrite problem?

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Recently I migrated my websites to another server that are using ISPCP. But, I am getting some trouble, the variables that are passing in the URL aren't being read.

Example:
the URL:
**http://www.site.com/index.php?page=show.php&id=4030**

should call "**show.php**" (show.php make a select in some table and show the result, it was working in the old server), but now this url just call "**index.php**" without interpret the parameters.

Is it some rewrite problem?

Apache log doenst show any error, it returns code 200... What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example, like `print_r($_GET);` in the index.php file?

Comment: Sure: http://www.site.com/index.php?page=show.php&id=4026
result:
Array ( [page] => show.php [id] => 4026 )

Comment: Sounds okay so far, doesn't it? If `show.php` isn't being called, you need to look in index.php why

Comment: For a long time I havent developing in PHP, has something changed? I just call "require_once("$HTTP_GET_VARS[page]");" in my index.php

Comment: Thanks Pekka, It was solved. I changed: "if (!$HTTP_GET_VARS['page'])" to "if (!$_GET['page'])"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in index.php

I just changed:

```
if ($HTTP_GET_VARS['page'])
   require_once("$HTTP_GET_VARS[page]");
```

)

to

```
if (!$_GET['page'])
   require_once($_GET['page']);
```

I just dont know why in the old server it was working...

Comment: The old server probably had PHP 4 or even older. However, this is a security risk - it allows outside attackers to gain access to other files in your system. See e.g. [How can I sanitize my include statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1799384) for how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

```
require_once($_GET['page'])
```

Anyway, this is a bad approach to including files. Completely insecure.